# Jenkins pipeline job forward build status to freestyle job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently using the Global Build Stats plugin that displays the status of our jobs in a nice well-formed chart.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin

However, some of our build jobs are implemented as a pipeline script and I recently learned that the Global Build Stats plugin does not support pipeline jobs.

One idea I had to workaround this idea was to create a freestyle job that gets triggered for each of my pipeline jobs.  The pipeline job would relay its own build status some how to the freestyle job.  I would then point my Global Build Stats plugin at this new freestyle job instead of the pipeline job.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create freestyle job with status parameter and then trigger this parameterized job from your pipeline (passing the status of your build as a parameter, e.g. `${currentBuild.currentResult}`).

If you need an example of triggering parameterized job, see [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221400287-How-to-pass-parameter-to-downstream-job-in-Pipeline-job-).